# C++17: Using C++ or C++11 libraries GDAL and OpenCV with C++17 application

Tags: c++, opencv, c++17, gdal

I am still rather new to C++ programming, and was going through the Pluralsight C++ beginner courses. One interesting thing is that in their "Beginner" sequence, the first course is on C++11, and the second course is "C++ Fundamentals including C++17."  So they are showing C++17 features and syntax.

My own goal is to use C++ for processing images and some geospatial data, so basically the GDAL, OGR, and OpenCV libraries. **My question is can I use the GDAL, or OpenCV libraries when I write an application in C++17?** In the Pluralsight course the instructor mentions that C++ code is backward compatible. So that should answer the question. However, I don't know if there are any caveats or limitations on this backward compatibility. Also, are there any special flags I need to add to the compile string, or to CMake?

Sorry if this is a really noobie question, but I did some googling and could not find a clear answer.

Comment: I think you have answered your own question, the GDAL libs can be referenced by any version *later* than the one that they were compiled on. though you should make an effort to get the libs compiled on the most recent version just in case you're missing out on some optimizations. Just make sure you get 32 or 64 bit libs to match your compile target. The only *special* change I've needed to make is to reference gdal_i.lib as an additional dependency.

Comment: @MichaelStimson Thanks for the info. Glad that I can get GDAL to work with C++ >= 11. It really helps that you have tried it with the newer C++ and it works. I found that with OpenCV there are some incompatibilities having to do with namespaces. But I have to check and see if anything has changed on that front.